# grails's validation-mobile,email seems to not work

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

I have a domain class which has two properties using email,mobile validation by grails, code like

```
strMobile attributes:[cn: "mobile", mobile:true]
strEmail  attributes:[cn: "email", email:true],nullable: true
```

and then I set

```
strMobile="abc1111",strEmail="111111",
```

execute validate method,but it doesnt return

```
strMobile,strEmail'Error.
```

Is it grails validation bug or I've done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use matches for mobile in constraint closure as there are no inbuilt constraint available for mobile(As I know). For email  you can use email:true like:

```
static constraints = {
   email nullable: true, email: true
   strMobile matches: "44[0-9]{10}" //Change Matcher As Per Your Requirement
}
```

Comment: If there are no inbuilt constraint available for mobile,it is no means to use mobile constraint ,just use matches is ok.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/ataylor284/grails-phonenumbers plugin for phone number validation if you want.